# Update multiple table column values based on json select query

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I just created 4 new columns in my database named `cea_no`, `district`, `property_type` and `listing_type`. I want to insert the result of them based on my select query into the new column that i added. The select query result is from the row `json` and it is extracted from a `json` data. How could I achieve that? I tried some methods and it worked, the problem is it inserts a new row and my data is now doubled.

My table structure.

```
+------------------+------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| Field            | Type       | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                         |
+------------------+------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| id               | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment                |
| json             | mediumtext | NO   |     | NULL                |                               |
| property_name    | text       | NO   |     | NULL                |                               |
| property_address | text       | NO   |     | NULL                |                               |
| price            | text       | NO   |     | NULL                |                               |
| listed_by        | text       | NO   |     | NULL                |                               |
| contact          | text       | NO   |     | NULL                |                               |
| cea_no           | text       | NO   |     | NULL                |       EMPTY  for now          |
| district         | text       | NO   |     | NULL                |       EMPTY  for now          |
| property_type    | text       | NO   |     | NULL                |       EMPTY  for now          |
| listing_type     | text       | NO   |     | NULL                |       EMPTY  for now          |
| update_time      | timestamp  | NO   |     | current_timestamp() | on update current_timestamp() |
+------------------+------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+
```

The query that I tried

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.agencyLicense') AS cea_no, 
JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.district') AS district, 
JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.details."Type"') AS property_type,
RIGHT(JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.details."Type"'),9) AS listing_type 
from xp_guru_listings;
```

Sample result which is correct

```
+------------------------------+----------+------------------------+--------------+
| cea_no                       | district | property_type          | listing_type |
+------------------------------+----------+------------------------+--------------+
| "CEA: R017722B \/ L3009740K" | "(D25)"  | "Apartment For Sale"   | For Sale"    |
| "CEA: R016023J \/ L3009793I" | "(D25)"  | "Condominium For Sale" | For Sale"    |
| "CEA: R011571E \/ L3002382K" | "(D25)"  | "Condominium For Sale" | For Sale"    |
| "CEA: R054044J \/ L3010738A" | "(D21)"  | "Apartment For Sale"   | For Sale"    |
| "CEA: R041180B \/ L3009250K" | "(D09)"  | "Condominium For Sale" | For Sale"    |
+------------------------------+----------+------------------------+--------------+
```

That is the values that I want to insert in the new columns.

EDIT:
I tried this query but it wont work

```
update xp_guru_listings cross join (
    SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.agencyLicense') AS cea_no, 
JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.district') AS district, 
JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.details."Type"') AS property_type,
RIGHT(JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.details."Type"'),9) AS listing_type 
from xp_guru_listings
)
set cea_no = cea_no, 
district = district, 
property_type = property_type, 
listing_type = listing_type;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an `INNER JOIN`, not a `CROSS JOIN` otherwise you will get incorrect data inserted. And you need to join on the appropriate condition which is that the `id` values match. This should work:

```
update xp_guru_listings x
join (
    SELECT id,
           JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.agencyLicense') AS cea_no, 
           JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.district') AS district, 
           JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.details."Type"') AS property_type,
           RIGHT(JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.details."Type"'),9) AS listing_type 
    FROM xp_guru_listings) j ON j.id = x.id
set x.cea_no = j.cea_no, 
    x.district = j.district, 
    x.property_type = j.property_type, 
    x.listing_type = j.listing_type;
```

Note that you could write this more simply using the `JSON_EXTRACT` formulas directly in the `SET` part of the `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE xp_guru_listings
SET cea_no = JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.agencyLicense'),
    district = JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.district'),
    property_type = JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.details."Type"'),
    listing_type = RIGHT(JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.details."Type"'),9)
```

Comment: Really sir? why would he get incorrect data by using cross join? please explain to me.

Comment: Why would i get incorrect data from using cross join sir?

Comment: Because a cross join joins every row of one table to every row of the other so there's no guarantee which row's data from derived table will be used to update the main table

Comment: I tried using your query sir but it returns ` Column 'cea_no' in field list is ambiguous` I just removed the `x` from the update statement

Comment: @user001232 Sorry - I left out the table aliases. See my edit.

Comment: Ahh I see. i did not include the id for every row. Thats why it is not guaranteed also. But if he uses this query it is 100% sure that in every column, he gets the correct value based on the result id right? @Nick

Comment: @user001232 Here's a demo of `cross join` vs `inner join` - you can see the update using `cross join` ended up with all table rows having the same value: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=90a95c46086922f536172e9bf4b93463

Comment: @Vince indeed. But *"In standard SQL, they are not equivalent. INNER JOIN is used with an ON clause, CROSS JOIN is used otherwise"*

Comment: okay sir. Thanks for the information. I now i know. and sorry for my wrong answer

Comment: @Vince no need to apologise - well, not to me anyway!

Comment: can i have a chat with you sir?  @Nick just want to help me with this tricky issue that i cant resolve myself

Comment: @user001232 why not just ask another question? btw I edited my answer with a simpler solution

Comment: cant ask another question. I can only ask one question at a time. Im sorry . and thanks for the edit of your answer @Nick

Comment: here please https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11391/sql it would be inappropriate if we comment here.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your query is correct. You just need to add an alias to your subquery in order for it to work. Its like this

```
UPDATE xp_guru_listings CROSS JOIN
(SELECT 
JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.agencyLicense') AS cea_no, 
JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.district') AS district, 
JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.details."Type"') AS property_type,
RIGHT(JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.details."Type"'),9) AS listing_type 
from xp_guru_listings) as x
set cea_no = cea_no, 
district = district, 
property_type = property_type, 
listing_type = listing_type;
```

Comment: Ohh I see. So that why it always returns `Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias `. Thanks a lot for this